# ASP.NET 4.5 - Modelbinding on User Control with Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, model-binding

My apologies if this question was asked before, but i'm developing a User Control with a `Gridview`. 
(the reason i'm doing this is because I want to re-use the Control on different pages in my Application).

I want to use `modelbinding` on this `Gridview`, but when I try to enable it, it doesn't work.
It gives me the following Errors when I try to compile:

`'IsValid' is not a member of 'System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelState'.`

`'AddModelError' is not a member of 'System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelState'.`

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test.ascx.vb" Inherits="Octoplus.test" %>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="Octoplus.OrderHeader" UpdateMethod="GridView1_UpdateItem">
```

```
Imports System.Web.ModelBinding
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

' The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
Public Sub GridView1_UpdateItem(ByVal id As Integer)
    Dim item As Octoplus.OrderHeader = Nothing
    ' Load the item here, e.g. item = MyDataLayer.Find(id)
    If item Is Nothing Then
        ' The item wasn't found
        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", id))
        Return
    End If
    TryUpdateModel(item)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ' Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges()

    End If
End Sub
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because ModelState is not member of UserControl but of Page. So you have to use the Page property from UserControl to access ModelState value:

```
If Page.ModelState.IsValid Then
    ' Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModelState` class in the namespace `System.Web.ModelBinding` simply does not have such properties as `IsValid` or `AddModelError`...

You can read about the available properties and methods of this class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.modelstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your problem is that you are trying to use the `ModelState` from `System.Web.Mvc` in your ASP.NET WebForms application.

The `ModelState` from the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace (applicable for ASP.NET MVC projects) does indeed have the property `IsValid` and `AddModelError` which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Comment: It is strange though that when I just create an empty Webform with a Gridview and enable Modelbinding on that Control, it doesn't give me the Error. I do have noticed that the ModelState then comes from the namespace: System.Web.Modelbinding.ModelstateDictionary.